# Button does not appear properly

Tags: html, facebook, button, facebook-login, facebook-authentication

I have a facebook login button, but it appears like normal text, and I don't know why. I wrote my code according to the facebook prescriptions I found [here](http://www.fbrell.com/fb.api/graph-me)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <ul>
      <li><fb:login-button scope="user_likes" id="get_like" onclick="<?php getLikes(); ?>">Get Liked pages</fb:login-button>
</li></ul>
```

When tested shows just the text "Get Liked pages"
Any idea?

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497170/cant-get-fb-login-button-to-show-up helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the JavaScript SDK code on your page to render the button? You also need to change the HTML tag to:

`<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">`

Consult the [JavaScript SDK Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#login).

Comment: Yeah, now they appear, except when I use 
      `<li><fb:login-button scope="user_apps" id="get_apps">Get Apps</fb:login-button></li>` 


No idea why this one doesn't appear. However for a second, i can see "Error" in red until it disappears

Comment: It's probably because `user_apps` isn't a valid scope / permission.